# JQuery: html() is not working as expected 

Tags: jquery

I have a **div**:

```
<div id="pageMessagesBox"></div>
```

In a java script function I am trying to add some items inside my **div**:

```
$("#pageMessagesBox").html("<a id='id'></a>");
```

But I've got the following result for `$("#pageMessagesBox").html()`:

```
"<A id=id></A>"
```

The expected is:

```
"<A id='id'></A>"
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: The HTML you get back is generated from the DOM, and as such, browser dependent.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong here. This output is expected and will function correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

> This method uses the browser's
>   innerHTML property. Some browsers may
>   not return HTML that exactly
>   replicates the HTML source in an
>   original document. For example,
>   Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off
>   the quotes around attribute values if
>   they contain only alphanumeric
>   characters.